# General Brouwer's theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, examples-counterexamples

Everything stated here occurs in a category where every map is a continuous map.
Suppose $C$ represents circle, $D$ represents Disc, and $P$ represents a Plane. Consider following maps:

- Inclusion of circle into disc, $j:C\rightarrow D$
- Inclusion of disc into plane, $i:D\rightarrow P$

Following is an observation:

$$\forall f, g: D\rightarrow P,$$ $(f\circ j = i\circ j) \ and \ (\exists o:C\rightarrow D \ s.t. \ g\circ j=i\circ o) \Rightarrow (\exists d:1\rightarrow D \ s.t. \ f\circ d= g\circ d) $.

Author has asked to test the above observation by constructing a counter-example. But so far, I have failed to do so. I have thought of it as concentric discs in plane, and then points inside the disc 1 move towards point $p1$ and points of disc 2 move towards point $p2$ (Imagine stretching a two dimensional rubber while standing at $p2$ perhaps via magnetism or something). But it still appears that, some points which are labelled the same by maps $f$ and $g$ move to the same location.

## Actual Text Pictures

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with category theory? You are looking at a statement about continuous maps on specific topological spaces.

Comment: @s.harp Question is found in book called "Conceptual Mathematics". I think statements like Brouwer's theorems are not only valid in topological spaces and continuous maps on them, but on also on smooth spaces and maps on them et cetera. Hence, conceivably, these categories are instances of much general category (With some added new things to this general category).

Comment: So, are you just looking for some category in which there are objects $C, D, P$ and morphisms $i, j$ that do *not* satisfy your property? Or does your category need to have some special properties? For instance, does it have to be a subcategory of Top? And does it have to be a full subcategory?

Comment: @Magdiragdag Author has not precisely defined the category $Top$. So, I am not sure what are asking. But, what I can say is, that explanation of this situation will prove/refute the observation. So, as the question states, you must consider all the continuous morphisms $D\rightarrow P$ with stated restriction. So, what I meant to say in last comment is that, Instead of precisely specifying the objects circle, disc.... you can extract the essence and explain the scenario in that context. I am posting an image of the text, perhaps, that will shed some light on confusion.